# A determinant of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Is there a way to write the following expression in terms of a determinant of one big matrix?

$\begin{align}
A&=(A_1A_2-A_3^2)(A_1A_4-A_5^2)-(A_1A_6-A_7^2)^2\\
&=det(\mathbf{B})det(\mathbf{C})-det(\mathbf{D})^2\\
&=det(\mathbf{E}), 
\end{align}$

where $A_i$ are scalars, and

$\begin{align}
\mathbf{B}&=\begin{bmatrix}A_1&A_3\\A_3&A_2\end{bmatrix}\\
\mathbf{C}&=\begin{bmatrix}A_1&A_5\\A_5&A_4\end{bmatrix}\\
\mathbf{D}&=\begin{bmatrix}A_1&A_7\\A_7&A_6\end{bmatrix}\\
\mathbf{E}&=\begin{bmatrix}det(\mathbf{B})&det(\mathbf{D})\\det(\mathbf{D})&det(\mathbf{C})\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$

In other words, I'm trying to write 
$A=det(\mathbf{X})$, where $\mathbf{X}$ is a big matrix with entries $A_i$

Cheers

Comment: What are $A_i$ and $A$?

Comment: $A_i$ are scalars (updated above)

Comment: The question isn't clear. Can you explain it more explicit manner?

Comment: Then use the fact that $ab-c^2=\left|\begin{matrix}a &c\\c &b\end{matrix}\right|$ four times.

Comment: @H.Ergül: I have updated the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do was

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & A_1 & 0\\
0 &1 & 0 & A_1\\
A_2 & A_6 & A_3^2 & A_7^2\\
A_6 & A_4 & A_7^2 & A_5^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
that has the required determinant. I'm starting to think there doesn't exists a matrix as asked.